# How to virtualize columns in react table

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7, react-window

We have use case to render more than 1000 columns with 100 rows (max). Now we need to virtualize column wise instead of row wise.

Is there is anyway to achieve it in react-table?

Comment: They do support hiding columns https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/column-hiding

Comment: we are already using this. In case they select all performance will be gone

Comment: This library doesn't seem to do what you are asking for. Perhaps limit the number of columns you allow to be shown at once?

Answer (score 1):

Use `react-virtual`, it will provide both horizontal & vertical virtualization and is pretty good. I don't have any example ready else would have shared that.

Ref - https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-virtual